# How to setListner to stop Animation and send callback to MainActivity Android

Tags: java, android, animation, interface, callback

How to use call back here to check if the Animation is completed or stopped it is giving me AnimationStoped listner as null.

I want to set Buttons in My main class when the animation is stopped but it is giving me nullpointer. I am having a hard time to understand this call back

```
public interface AnimationStopCheckListner {
    void callback(boolean result);
}


   public class AnimationsContainer implements AnimationStopCheckListner {
    public int FPS = 30;  // animation FPS

    // single instance procedures
    private static AnimationsContainer mInstance;
    boolean endAnim = false;

    private AnimationsContainer() {
    }

    public static AnimationsContainer getInstance() {
        if (mInstance == null)
            mInstance = new AnimationsContainer();
        return mInstance;
    }


    public final int[] IMAGE_RESOURCES = {R.drawable.menu_000,
            R.drawable.menu_0001, R.drawable.menu_0002, R.drawable.menu_0003,
            R.drawable.menu_0004, R.drawable.menu_0005, R.drawable.menu_0006,
            R.drawable.menu_0007, R.drawable.menu_0008,
            R.drawable.menu_0009, R.drawable.menu_00010
    };


    /**
     * @param imageView
     * @return splash screen animation
     */
    public FramesSequenceAnimation createSplashAnim(ImageView imageView) {
        return new FramesSequenceAnimation(imageView, IMAGE_RESOURCES, FPS);
    }

    @Override
    public void callback(boolean result) {

    }

    /**
     * AnimationPlayer. Plays animation frames sequence in loop
     */

    public class FramesSequenceAnimation {
        private int[] mFrames; // animation frames
        private int mIndex; // current frame
        private boolean mShouldRun; // true if the animation should continue running. Used to stop the animation
        private boolean mIsRunning; // true if the animation currently running. prevents starting the animation twice
        private SoftReference<ImageView> mSoftReferenceImageView; // Used to prevent holding ImageView when it should be dead.
        private Handler mHandler;
        private int mDelayMillis;
        private Bitmap mBitmap = null;
        Context mcontext;
        private BitmapFactory.Options mBitmapOptions;
        AnimationStopCheckListner animationStopCheckListner;


        public void setOnAnimationFramesSequenceAnimation(AnimationStopCheckListner listener) {
            this.animationStopCheckListner = listener;
            Log.e("setinterface", "setting");
        }

        public FramesSequenceAnimation(ImageView imageView, int[] frames, int fps) {
            mHandler = new Handler();
            mFrames = frames;
            mIndex = -1;
            mSoftReferenceImageView = new SoftReference<>(imageView);
            mShouldRun = false;
            mIsRunning = false;
            mDelayMillis = 100 / fps;

            imageView.setImageResource(mFrames[0]);

            // use in place bitmap to save GC work (when animation images are the same size & type)
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 11) {
                Bitmap bmp = ((BitmapDrawable) imageView.getDrawable()).getBitmap();
                int width = bmp.getWidth();
                int height = bmp.getHeight();
                Bitmap.Config config = bmp.getConfig();
                mBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(width, height, config);
                mBitmapOptions = new BitmapFactory.Options();
                // setup bitmap reuse options.
                mBitmapOptions.inBitmap = mBitmap;
                mBitmapOptions.inMutable = true;
                mBitmapOptions.inSampleSize = 1;
            }
        }

        private int getNext() {
            mIndex++;
            if (mIndex >= mFrames.length)
                mIndex = 0;

            Log.e("total frames", String.valueOf(mIndex));

            if (mIndex == 58) {

                AnimationsContainer.mInstance.endAnim = true;
                stop();
                setOnAnimationFramesSequenceAnimation(animationStopCheckListner);
                if (animationStopCheckListner != null) {
                    // this is null
                    animationStopCheckListner.callback(true);
                }
            }
            return mFrames[mIndex];
        }

        /**
         * Starts the animation
         */
        public synchronized void start() {
            mShouldRun = true;
            if (mIsRunning)
                return;

            Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    ImageView imageView = mSoftReferenceImageView.get();
                    if (!mShouldRun || imageView == null) {
                        mIsRunning = false;
                          /*  if (mOnAnimationStoppedListener != null) {
                                mOnAnimationStoppedListener.onAnimationStopped();
                            }*/
                        return;
                    }

                    mIsRunning = true;
                    mHandler.postDelayed(this, mDelayMillis);

                    if (imageView.isShown()) {
                        int imageRes = getNext();
                        if (mBitmap != null) { // so Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 11
                            Bitmap bitmap = null;
                            try {
                                bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(imageView.getResources(), imageRes, mBitmapOptions);
                            } catch (Exception e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                            if (bitmap != null) {
                                imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
                            } else {
                                imageView.setImageResource(imageRes);
                                mBitmap.recycle();
                                mBitmap = null;
                            }
                        } else {
                            imageView.setImageResource(imageRes);
                        }
                    }
                }
            };

            mHandler.post(runnable);

        }

        /**
         * Stops the animation
         */
        public synchronized void stop() {
            mShouldRun = false;

        }
    }

}
```

Comment: listner is null because you are may be not setting it your MainActivity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

listner is null because you are may be not setting it your MainActivity

Try it like this.

```
MainActivty extends AppCompatActivity implements AnimationStopCheckListner
```

write it in your onCreate function

```
 AnimationsContainer.getInstance.setOnAnimationFrameSequenceAnimation(this);
```

and then

```
  public void callback(boolean result){
    // do your stuff
}
```